# How to include indentation / white spaces / tabs in an html that is contained in an xml document

Tags: html, xml, whitespace, indentation

I have a xml template file that is being used as an email template.

I can't use &emsp in the html body as it indicates as the xml is not valid when I try to load it in. I tried using cdata, but it doesn't adjust the html text. I need to have indentation in the body of the email.

I'm looking for an example of a xml document containing html body which includes indentation / tab / white space.

Also, if someone can point me to reference documents, that would be awesome too.

thanks!

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Also please explain what you mean by indentation. You can use blockquote

Comment: When I copy the html directly out and open it with a browser, it shows right when I use &emsp. But as I xml doesn't like it, I need to figure out a way to have indentation in the body of the html, such as 4 spaces, a tab, etc.

When I try to use cdata, it doesn't format the text.

I can't find an example yet that is regarding white spacing or tab spacing within an html that is contained in an XML file.

It needs to be valid xml, but still work in html, when the email template runs.

Comment: Using blockquote provided the solution. Thank you!